# Got script to work once, then it stopped with Run-Time Error '1004'

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

I found several questions of a similar instance on this site, but none of the solutions worked for me.

My objective is to allow the user to click a button in a spread sheet and either a) save the entire workbook locally or b)export only a section of the book to a PDF.

The "save as" code works just fine and the export to pdf code worked once then stopped working. Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()

Dim workbook_file_name As String
Dim datasheet As String
Dim saveworkbook As Double
Dim PDFdata As Object

saveworkbook = MsgBox("Would you like to save a local copy of entire workbook? Click No to only store as PDF", vbYesNo, "Save File As")

If saveworkbook = vbYes Then

    workbook_file_name = "Sherman and Reilly Brake Test"

        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
            .InitialFileName = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Specialfolders("My Documents") & "\" & workbook_file_name
            .FilterIndex = 2

                If .Show Then .Execute
        End With

    GoTo noPDF

Else

    GoTo exportsheet

End If

exportsheet:

datasheet = "C:\Brake_Test_Data.pdf"

If Dir(datasheet) <> vbNullString Then
    Kill datasheet
End If

Set PDFdata = Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("A93:I138")

With PDFdata

    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=datasheet, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True


End With

noPDF:

End Sub
```

I have tired to dimension PDFdata to variant as well. The issue appears to be here:

```
.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=datasheet, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

I get Run Time Error 1004 and the message box that says the document did not save and the document may be open or an error occurred while saving.

Comment: Not an expert on VBA I/O but is it not because the file already exists

Comment: @Casey I've thought of that, which is why I added the directory search. Even still, I've gone and deleted the first pdf file when the script works, so there no longer exists that file.

Comment: I took your code, deleted everything from `saveworkbook = ...` down to `exportsheet:`, and then ran it.  I had no troubles running it multiple times (providing I remembered to close Acrobat Reader after each execution).

Comment: FWIW (it shouldn't be related to the problem) `PDFdata` should be declared `As Range` rather than `As Object` or `As Variant`.

Comment: @YowE3K, I do need the first bit for the save as, however, I tried what you did and got the same error.

Comment: Does the file exist when you get the error?  (I know it **shouldn't** exist, but does it?)

Comment: No, I’ve made sure to go and delete it. If I type a full address I can get it to work, however, if someone else is using the program, they wont have my exact file directory on their computer. I don’t know why, C:/ or leaving the file path to default doesn’t work.

Comment: So the issue is not that the file can't be written twice in a row to the same location, it's that it can be written to one location but not to the root directory of the `C:\` drive?  Do you have write access to the root directory?  (Often IT departments set computers up so that the non-IT staff can't modify the root directory.)

Comment: That I’m not sure of. However, when it worked the first time, I didn’t have a path set and it saved to my documents.

Comment: Try writing a file to the root directory.  Just go into Windows Explorer, copy some dummy file, and try pasting it to the root directory.  That will soon tell you whether the issue is simply that you can't write to the root directory.

Comment: `I didn’t have a path set and it saved to my documents` - `My Documents` is not in root directory. (Or maybe it is by extension, but its open for users to save stuff.

Comment: @YowE3K So, it turns out, I can’t write to the c drive. So I tried using my documents (which I can write to) but that didn’t work either.

Comment: Did it not work for the same reason, i.e. "the document may be open or an error occurred while saving"?  What was the value of `datasheet` that you were using?  (Feel free to obfuscate the actual value a bit for privacy purposes if you like, i.e. substitute different letters, but preferably leave all non-alphanumeric characters exactly as they are.)  Did the file exist when it crashed?  (Again, I know it **shouldn't** exist, but does it?)

Comment: So I went ahead a tried a different approach, but still not getting the result I want:


Set mydocuments = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders
Set saveto = mydocuments("mydocuments")
Set PDFdata = Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("A93:I138")

With PDFdata

    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=saveto & "\Brake Test.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True


End With

Answer (score 0):

@YowE3K, I figured it out

```
Option Explicit

Dim workbook_file_name As String
Dim datasheet As String
Dim saveworkbook As Double
Dim PDFdata As Range
Dim mydocuments As Object
Dim saveto As String

Sub Button1_Click()


saveworkbook = MsgBox("Would you like to save a local copy of entire workbook? Click No to only store as PDF", vbYesNo, "Save File As")

If saveworkbook = vbYes Then

    workbook_file_name = "*****"

       With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
            .InitialFileName = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("My Documents") & "\" & workbook_file_name
            .FilterIndex = 2

                If .Show Then .Execute
        End With

    GoTo noPDF

Else

    GoTo exportsheet

End If

exportsheet:

Set mydocuments = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders
saveto = mydocuments("mydocuments")
Set PDFdata = Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("A93:I138")

With PDFdata

    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=saveto & "\*****.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True


End With

noPDF:


Sheets("Data Sheet").Protect Password:="*****"

End Sub
```

What I did was have the code find the mydocs folder then set is as a string. Thank you for you help!